# Enable/Disable form elements based on dropdown list

Tags: jquery

So I have been looking around at questions on here and I have gotten far enough to be able to disable a `textbox` by changing the selection of the `dropdownlist`, but I want to be able to enable it again if the `dropdownlist` goes back to its default value of `<Select an Access Point>`.

JQuery:

```
$('#selectAccessPoint').change(function () {
    if ($('#selectAccessPoint :selected').val != "2147483647")
        $('#newAccessPoint').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else {
        $('#newAccessPoint').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#newAccessPoint').attr('enabled', 'enabled');
    }
});
```

HTML for `textbox` and `dropdownlist`:
`

```
        <tr>
        <td><label for ="AccessPoint" class="xl">Access Point:</label></td>
            <td><%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AccessPointsList.Id, Model.AccessPointsList.AccessPoints.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.AsDecimal()), new { @id = "selectAccessPoint", @class = "info1"})%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for ="AccessPoint" class="xl">Or Add New:</label></td>
            <td><%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AccessPointsList.AccessPoint, new { @id = "newAccessPoint", @class = "location info2 xl", maxlength = "250" }) %></td>
        </tr>
```

Generated HTML:
`<select class="info1" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="selectAccessPoint" name="AccessPointsList.Id"><option value="2147483647">&lt;Select an Access Point&gt;</option>`
(there are more options in there but this is the one I am comparing against)

`<input class="location info2 xl" id="newAccessPoint" maxlength="250" name="AccessPointsList.AccessPoint" type="text" value="">`

Notes: `attr` must be used as `prop` gives me an error and `val()` also gives me an error.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: My best guess would be something like 1.6.2, I am working on editing/adding to a solution developed by somebody else and that's the only version number I can find for any of it

Comment: You can programmatically retrieve the version using `$().jquery`. I suggest carefully reading through the API as there are a number of elementary errors here.

Comment: I would just throw `$().jquery` anywhere in my js file?

Comment: @Jared you can do it right in the console.. hit F12 - type in the console and run

Comment: Ahhh Thank you, 1.4.4.  I"ll look through the documentation

Comment: when you inspect the dom.. is the select/dropdown id still `selectAccessPoint`?

Comment: @wirey Yes it is. And oddly enough, according to [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/val/) val() was introduced in v1.0 so I'm still not sure why I can't use it

Comment: @Jared try just getting the val of the select.. not the selected option like this $('#selectAccessPoint').val() - you can do that right in the console also if you want.  hmm can you add the generated html to the question?

Comment: @wirey Well that executed in the console, I'm guessing your suggesting I use that value as the value for the logical test?

Comment: @Jared that's actually your choice.. but it just makes more sense to check the value of the select instead of the text since the value attribute has it's purpose..  the reason why your selector isn't working is because missing `$` in front `('#selectAccessPoint:selected')` and also missing the space between `selectAccessPoint :selected` - then missing () after the text.. but it would be much easier to troubleshoot if we could see the actual generated HTML

Comment: @wirey I have updated my original post with the generated html from the DOM and with your fixes to my JQuery code but still no luck. Blah.

Comment: @wirey Palash found a solution down there and it didn't give me an error using the `.text()` method

Comment: @Jared ok.. here's two other ways you can do it [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/9Zjmw/)

Comment: @wirey Those are excellent as well.  I'm going to keep all of these somewhere as reference so that I don't have to both the community with my silliness again hopefully.  I really hope one day I can be as helpful as you and Palash.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Using jquery v1.9.1

```
$('#selectAccessPoint').change(function () {
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() != '<Select an Access Point>') {
        $('#newAccessPoint').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#newAccessPoint').prop('disabled', false)
    }
});
```

- `$('#selectAccessPoint:selected')` not correct. It should be `$('#selectAccessPoint option:selected')`
- `.text` not correct. It should be `.text()`
- To **disable** a textbox simply use this `prop('disabled', true)` using the jquery v1.9.1.
- To **enable** a textbox simply use this `prop('disabled', false)`.

### Using jquery v1.4.4

```
$('#selectAccessPoint').change(function () {
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() != 'Select an Access Point') {
        $('#newAccessPoint').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#newAccessPoint').attr('disabled', '')
    }
});
```

Comment: My version of jquery does not support `prop` or the `text` method.  Thank you though.

Comment: I see that, and I understand that it will work for newer versions of jquery, but this application only has 1.4.4 and its not up to me to change that.  I have to work with what I've got.  Thank you.

Comment: @Jared OK let me see that.

Comment: What would you like to see?

Comment: @Jared: I was tryin to work on the fiddle with jquery v1.4.4 but there is no option for that version :/

Comment: @PalashMondal just select `No-Library (pure JS)` on the left.. then external resources add `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this

HTML

```
<select name="foo" id="foo" onChange="javascript:changeTextBoxState(this)">
  <option>Select Something</option>
  <option>FooBar</option>
</select>

<input name="bar" id="bar" type="text" />
```

jQuery

```
function changeTextBoxState(dropDown) {

  switch (dropDown.value) {
    case 'Select Something': {
       $('#bar').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    case 'FooBar': {
       $('#bar').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }
}
```

There is no enabled attribute on input tag only disabled.

Hope this helps

Comment: I might have to.  I was just hoping to try and keep this strictly to JQuery but that's not a very big change. Hmmm.